# Unable to start emulator after build AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I can't run "emulator" after rebuild Android Open Source Project on Ubuntu 10.0.4. Please take a look at below error details then tell me if you know how. Thanks.

> No command 'emulator' found, did you mean:  Command 'qemulator' from
>   package 'qemulator' (universe) emulator: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator  is added to current path when I run

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
```

Comment: Even I did the same, but the emulator is not getting added to the path. I did `lunch aosp_arm-eng` after the first step.

Answer (score 11):

After:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
```

Please try running:

```
set_stuff_for_environment
```

then see if the emulator command works.

Answer (score 3):

`emulator` is a binary that should be located at `prebuilts/android-emulator/<platform>/`, e.g. `prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/`. As mentioned, the `lunch` command will add this directory to your `PATH`.