# Unable to build android due to incorrect java

Tags: android, c, build, java

I have ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to build android for BBB. I got BBB android and visited this site to get the correct java.

I took android source from this site

http://bbbandroid.sourceforge.net/build.html

then followed steps for java from this site,

https://source.android.com/source/initializing#for-ubuntu-14-04

I did as the site said.

then **make -j4** gave this build error,

```
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
************************************************************
You are attempting to build with an unsupported JDK.

You use OpenJDK but only Sun/Oracle JDK is supported.
Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    https://source.android.com/source/download.html
************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:152: *** stop.  Stop.
```

Then I did this

```
**java -version**
openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3

**sudo update-alternatives --config javac**
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1081      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

again I checked the **java -version**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Its still same as previously.

1. What is the problem here?
2. What exactly is supported by google's android, oracle jdk, sun jdk or open jdk?

Comment: Under the assumption OpenJDK is OK and if remember correctly, you should also update `javah`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Sun/Oracle JDK, and you are currently using the OpenJDK.

Sun/Oracle JDK is the JDK supported. (Sun is owned by Oracle)

The makefile output answered your question.  It must be checking and enforcing the use of Sun/Oracle JDK.

> You use OpenJDK but only Sun/Oracle JDK is supported.
>
> Please follow the machine setup instructions at
>       https://source.android.com/source/download.html

You need to install the Sun/Oracle JDK and then run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Pick the newly installed version.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I solve this error by reboot computer, `make` again and the error is gone by unknown reason. But now I just found myself very ridiculous when I try to start the emulator.

Need to re-source to make emulator run with correct environment, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12909497/1074998)

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/android_src/hole$ . build/envsetup.sh
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/android_src/hole$ lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug
```

Now run the emulator:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/android_src/hole$ emulator -sysdir out/target/product/generic/ -system out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic/userdata.img -kernel prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7 -memory 2048
emulator: ERROR: Can't access ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT as '/home/xiaobai/Downloads/android_src/hole/out/target/product/bullhead'
You need to build the Android system before launching the emulator
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/android_src/hole$
```

I just realized I only has `/home/xiaobai/Downloads/android_src/hole/out/target/product/generic/`, no such `bullhead`  (Nexus 5X).

Now I know the reason why I success last time after reboot, this is because of it build with default generic lunch menu `aosp_arm-eng`, since I didn't redo the steps `. build/envsetup.sh` and `lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug` before rerun `make`.

And I can see my `/etc/environment` has this `JAVA_HOME` set, so `sudo update-alternatives --config java` never work since `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/` is Oracle/Sun, not Open JDK (my case is difference with OP,  whether requires one of Oracle/Sun or OpenJDK depends on lunch menu):

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$PATH"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/"
```

Modify the `/etc/environment` to openjdk path (In Ubuntu, it can be download with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`, then use `dpkg -L openjdk-8-jdk` to locate the path ), open a new tab shell session, redo the `. build/envsetup.sh`, `lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug`, and `make`, now it works without jdk error.